# Why we have $N_{1}+N_{2}+\cdots+N_{n}=N_{1}\oplus N_{2}\oplus\cdots\oplus N_{n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

Let $R$-module $M$ be a direct sum of modules $M_{1},M_{2},...,M_{n}$ and for each $i=\overline{1,n}$, $N_{i}\leq M_{i}$ ($N_{i}$ is submodule of $M_{i}$). Why we have $N_{1}+N_{2}+\cdots+N_{n}=N_{1}\oplus N_{2}\oplus\cdots\oplus N_{n}$ and $M/\left(\oplus_{i=1}^{n}N_{i}\right)\cong\oplus_{i=1}^{n}\left(M_{i}/N_{i}\right)$?

Comment: your question is not so clear... could you please rephrase it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote by $\times$ the “external” direct sum just to avoid confusion. Saying that
$$
N_1+N_2+\dots+N_n=N_1\oplus N_2\oplus\dots\oplus N_n
$$
means that the obvious homomorphism
$$
N_1\times N_2\times\dots\times N_n\to N_1+N_2+\dots+N_n
$$
is injective.

Hint for the second part: you can define homomorphisms
$$
M_i\to 
M\big/\left(\textstyle\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}N_{i}\right)
\quad(i=1,2,\dots,n)
$$
in a very natural way. What are their kernels?

Comment: I've the first part of my problem. How about the second?